# Remove blank option from country dropdown list

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, core, address

To generate country drop down list `Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect()` method is responsible but generated drop down has blank entry at the top along with all other countries.

How to remove this blank entry from country drop down list?

Comment: I think this is a bad idea, if you have more than one entry. If this os the vase and the user forgets to choose one, the country is wrong (in most cases)

Answer (score 5):

This might be late but I think very short & sweet solution :-

The file is this -

> app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Block/Data.php

and the function is this - `getCountryHtmlSelect`

If you want to remove the very top blank entry from country drop down....just put `false` in `toOptionArray(false);`

Don't forget that you put this file in `app/code/local/Mage` this is the good practice to keep the core file untouched :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
   $countryList = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                ->loadData()
                ->toOptionArray(false);
?>
   <select class="required-entry" id="county" name="county">         
     <?php foreach ($countryList as $key => $value) {?>
     <option value="<?php echo $value['label']; ?>"><?php echo $value['label']; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

You can try above code to access the countries list it's working very fine.

Answer (score 0):

For **Magento 2** this issue fixes via little plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\ResourceModel\Country;

/**
 * Plugin for processing incoming arguments of the method that leading to displaying additional empty dropdown.
 */
class Collection
{
    /**
     * Arguments processing.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject
     * @param bool $emptyLabel
     *
     * @return bool|array
     */
    public function beforeToOptionArray(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject,
        $emptyLabel = null
    ) {
        return is_null($emptyLabel) ? [''] : null;
    }
}
```

enjoy:)

Comment: Q was tagged with Magento 1 ...

Comment: hi @Dmitry, Its not working for me, pls provide full code, with di.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection">
        <plugin name="update_country_empty_option"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ResourceModel\Country\Collection" />
    </type>
</config>

Comment: @jafarpinjar you should update "Vendor\Module" with your namespaces.